# How can I make an email template from a React app after populating it with API data?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-email, nodemailer

I have to create a web page with React, populate it with foreign data from an API, and then export it to static HTML so that it can be sent as an email template to users. How can I achieve this?

I can create the application itself, and populate it with data, but is there some elegant way to take a snapshot of the app after it has the necessary asynchronous data, and make a file out of it that I can send through email?

I've only used React to develop web apps in the past, so im not sure what to look for but so far I have found [React-Snap](https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap) which seems like it may help me achieve this.

The end result should be some HTML that I can send in an email to users which is visually the same as the react application when it is running *after* being populated with data.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing.  I found https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Comment: If you want the email to use the same HTML as your app then be prepared to rewrite your frontend HTML. Email HTML is rife with problems due to the fragmented nature of email clients. For example, Outlook will render HTML differently than Gmail.

I recommend modifying an existing email template (there's lots on GitHub) to match your branding, use a templating language to merge in required dynamic data, and _then_ send the email.

Comment: For anyone reading this, I've been able to achieve my desired behavior by using NextJS's static site generation (getStaticProps).

Comment: how did you use getStatic to achieve this